# Object Tracking using Opencv and JavaCamera

Tags: android, opencv, flip

As I use the back camera to cap a frame, by default the Android application is landscape so to get the input frame I use

```
Core.flip(currentFrame, currentFrame, 1);//flip around Y-axi
```

After some image enhancement and `findcontour` using opencv,

I have the following problems:

a. Object moves left hand side, drawcirle moves downward.
 b. Object moves right hand side, drawcircle moves upward.
 c. Object moves upward, drawcircile moves left hand side.
 d. Object moves downward, drawcircle moves right hand side.

In other word, the drawcircle (output) should be clockwise 90 to get the image of the source [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sR2OQ.png).

Code shown as follows:

```
package com.mtyiuaa.writingintheair;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.ViewDebug;
import android.widget.Button;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.opencv.android.BaseLoaderCallback;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase;
import org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView;
import org.opencv.android.LoaderCallbackInterface;
import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfPoint;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.core.Size;
import org.opencv.core.Rect;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Moments;
import org.opencv.highgui.VideoCapture;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements   CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2{

private static final int THRESH_BINARY = 1;
private static final  int THRESH_TOZERO = 4;

private static String TAG = "MainActivity";

JavaCameraView javaCameraView;
JavaCameraView javaCameraView2;
VideoCapture videoCapture;
Mat mRgba;
Mat temp;
Mat previousFrame;
Mat GpreviousFrame; // gray-level frame of previous Frame
Mat currentFrame;
Mat GcurrentFrame; // gray-level frame of current Frame
Mat diffFrame;
Mat imgGray;
Mat imgHSV;
Mat imgCanny;
Mat inputFrame;
Mat FlipFrame;
Mat outputFrame;
Mat imgthresholding;
Mat imgNormalization;
Mat imgGaussianSmothing;
int max_Binary_value = 255;
int thresh = 20;
Boolean CameraActive;
Boolean firstIteration= true;
int[] theObject = {0,0};

int x=0, y=0;
int FRAME_WIDTH = 1280;
int FRAME_HEIGHT = 720;
//max number of objects to be detected in frame
int MAX_NUM_OBJECTS=50;
//Minimum and Maximum object area
int MIN_OBJECT_AREA = 20*20;
int MAX_OBJECT_AREA = (int) ((FRAME_HEIGHT*FRAME_WIDTH)/1.5);


//MatOfPoint allcontours = new MatOfPoint();
//bounding rectangle of the object, we will use the center of this as its position.


BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallBack = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
    @Override
    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
        switch(status){
            case BaseLoaderCallback.SUCCESS:{
                javaCameraView.enableView();
                //javaCameraView2.enableView();
                break;
            }
            default:{
                super.onManagerConnected(status);
                break;
            }
        }

    }
};

static{

}
//JavaCameraView javaCameraView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    javaCameraView = (JavaCameraView)findViewById(R.id.java_camera_view);
    javaCameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);
    javaCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);


@Override
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    if(javaCameraView!=null) {
        CameraActive = false;
        javaCameraView.disableView();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy(); // call the basic function
    if(javaCameraView!=null){
        javaCameraView.disableView();
    }

}

@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume(); //call based class
    if(OpenCVLoader.initDebug()){
        Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");
        mLoaderCallBack.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS);
        //grab a new instance by using Basecallbackloader


    }
    else {
        Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV not loaded");
        //recall opencvLoader if not loaded
        OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_10, this, mLoaderCallBack);
    }


}

@Override
public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
    //Mat::Mat(int rows, int cols, int type)
    // initialize all Mat object when onCamera starts
    CameraActive = true;
    // 4 channels are used
    mRgba = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8SC4);
    FlipFrame = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8SC4);
    previousFrame =new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8SC4);
    currentFrame = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8SC4);
    diffFrame =new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8SC4);

    // 1 channel is used.
    GcurrentFrame = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8SC1);
    GpreviousFrame = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8SC1);
    imgGray= new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8SC1);
    imgHSV = new Mat (height, width, CvType.CV_8SC1);
    imgCanny = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8SC1);
    imgGaussianSmothing = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8SC1);
    imgthresholding = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8SC1);
    imgNormalization = new Mat(height,width, CvType.CV_8SC1);
    inputFrame = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8SC1);
    outputFrame = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8SC1);
    temp = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8SC1);
}

@Override
public void onCameraViewStopped() {
    mRgba.release();
    FlipFrame.release();
    previousFrame.release();
    currentFrame.release();
    diffFrame.release();

    GcurrentFrame.release();
    GpreviousFrame.release();
    imgGray.release();
    imgHSV.release();
    imgCanny.release();
    imgGaussianSmothing.release();
    imgthresholding.release();
    imgNormalization.release();
    inputFrame.release();
    outputFrame.release();
    temp.release();
    CameraActive = false;


}

@Override
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {

    while(CameraActive) {
        Mat temp2 = new Mat();
        Mat temp3 = new Mat();


        currentFrame = inputFrame.rgba();
        Core.flip(currentFrame, currentFrame, 1);//flip aroud Y-axis


        RGB2HSV(currentFrame).copyTo(temp2);
        FilterHSVImage(temp2).copyTo(temp2);
        //CannyDetector(temp2).copyTo(temp4);
        MorphOperation(temp2).copyTo(temp2);
        List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<>();
        Mat hierarchy = new Mat();
        Imgproc.findContours(temp2,contours,hierarchy,Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

        temp2.copyTo(temp3);
        FindLargestContours(temp3, contours);



        //return outputFrame;
    }

    return null;
}



// Edge Detector using Canny
// Goal: Edge image is less sensitive to lighting conditon
public Mat CannyDetector(Mat inputFrame) {

    Imgproc.Canny(inputFrame, imgCanny, 50, 150);
    return imgCanny;
}




private Mat RGB2Gray (Mat inputFrame){

    Imgproc.cvtColor(inputFrame, imgGray, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
    return imgGray;
}

private Mat RGB2HSV (Mat inputFrame){
    Imgproc.cvtColor(inputFrame, imgHSV, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV);
    return imgHSV;
}

private Mat FilterHSVImage(Mat inputFrame){
    Core.inRange(inputFrame, new Scalar(0, 100, 100), new Scalar(10, 255, 255), imgthresholding);
    //Core.inRange(temp2, new Scalar(160, 100, 100), new Scalar(179, 255, 255), temp2);

    return imgthresholding;
}

private Mat MorphOperation (Mat inputFrame){

    //Mat element1 = Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_RECT, new  Size(2*dilation_size + 1, 2*dilation_size+1));
    //Imgproc.dilate(source, destination, element1);
    //Highgui.imwrite("dilation.jpg", destination);
    Mat erodeElement =Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_RECT, new Size(3,3));
    Mat dilateElement = Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_RECT, new Size (8,8));

    Imgproc.dilate(inputFrame, inputFrame, erodeElement);
    Imgproc.dilate(inputFrame, inputFrame, erodeElement);

    Imgproc.erode(inputFrame, inputFrame, dilateElement);
    Imgproc.erode(inputFrame, inputFrame, dilateElement);
    return inputFrame;
}



private Mat Threshold(Mat inputFrame){

    Imgproc.threshold(inputFrame, imgthresholding, thresh, max_Binary_value, Imgproc.THRESH_TOZERO);
    return imgthresholding;
}

private Mat ThresholdToBinary(Mat inputFrame){
    Imgproc.threshold(inputFrame, imgthresholding, thresh, max_Binary_value, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);
    //Imgproc.threshold(inputFrame, imgthresholding, thresh, max_Binary_value, THRESH_BINARY);
    return imgthresholding;
}
private Mat Normalization(Mat inputFrame, double min, double max){
    //double E_Max =

    Core.normalize(inputFrame, imgNormalization, min, max, Core.NORM_MINMAX);
    return imgNormalization;
}


private Mat drawObject(int x, int y, Mat inputFrame) {
    Point point = new Point(x, y);
    Point pointA = new Point(x, y - 25);
    Point pointB = new Point(x, y + 25);
    Point pointC = new Point(x - 25, y);
    Point pointD = new Point(x + 25, y);
    Scalar scalar = new Scalar(255, 0, 0);


        Core.circle(inputFrame,point,20,scalar,2);

        if(y-25>0) Core.line(inputFrame,point,pointA,scalar,2);
        else Core.line(inputFrame,point,new Point(x,0),scalar,2);
        if(y+25<FRAME_HEIGHT) Core.line(inputFrame,point,pointB,scalar,2);
        else Core.line(inputFrame,point,new Point(x,FRAME_HEIGHT),scalar,2);
        if(x-25>0)Core.line(inputFrame,point,pointC,scalar,2);
        else Core.line(inputFrame,point,new Point(0,y),scalar,2);
        if(x+25<FRAME_WIDTH) Core.line(inputFrame,point,pointD,scalar,2);
        else Core.line(inputFrame,point,new Point(FRAME_WIDTH,y),scalar,2);
        Core.putText(inputFrame, "Tracking object at (" + Integer.toString(x)+" , "+ Integer.toString(y)+ ")",point, 1, 1,scalar, 2);
       // putText(inputFrame,intToString(x)+","+intToString(y),Point(x,y+30),1,1,Scalar(0,255,0),2);
        Log.i(TAG, "Draw x at "+Integer.toString(x)+ "  Draw y at "+ Integer.toString(y));

    inputFrame.copyTo(outputFrame);
    return outputFrame;
}


private void TrackFilteredObject (int x, int y, Mat filteredImage, Mat sourceImage){
    boolean objectFound = false;
    Mat temp3 = new Mat();
    filteredImage.copyTo(temp3);
    List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
    Mat hierarchy = new Mat();
    Imgproc.findContours(temp3,contours,hierarchy,Imgproc.RETR_CCOMP, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    //Point[] contourPoints = (Point[]) contours.toArray();
    double refArea = 0;


    if (hierarchy.size().height>0 && hierarchy.size().width>0){
       // int numObjects = hierarchy.size();
        //if number of objects greater than MAX_NUM_OBJECTS we have a noisy filter

        //if(numObjects<MAX_NUM_OBJECTS) {
            for (int index = 0; index >= 0; index =(int)hierarchy.get(index,0)[0]){
                    //hierarchy[index][0]) {

                Moments moment = Imgproc.moments(contours.get(index), true);
                double area = moment.get_m00();

                //if the area is less than 20 px by 20px then it is probably just noise
                //if the area is the same as the 3/2 of the image size, probably just a bad filter
                //we only want the object with the largest area so we safe a reference area each
                //iteration and compare it to the area in the next iteration.
                if (area > MIN_OBJECT_AREA && area < MAX_OBJECT_AREA && area > refArea) {
                   // x = moment.m10 / area;
                    x= (int) (moment.get_m10()/area);
                    y = (int) (moment.get_m01()/area);
                    objectFound = true;
                    refArea = area;
                } else objectFound = false;
            }
        //}
    }
}



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace x with y, it's pretty simple man come on